# Problema al exportar base de datos MySQL, DISABLE KEYS - ENABLE KEYS

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

estoy realizando la exportación de distintas bases de datos mediante consola, la cuestión es que en todas ellas cuando reviso el archivo exportado veo lineas comentadas con;

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `************` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `************` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

y esto me ocurre en distintas DB ya sea una pequeña de apenas 16Mb o con una de 6GB con miles de inserciones.

¿Alguien sabría decirme el por que sucede esto y si a la hora de importar la DB me va a dar algún problema?

El comando que utilizo para exportar el fichero es este:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database > database.sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No deberíás tener problemas al restaurar esos backups.

Esas lineas están comentadas (/*......*/).

Cuando utilizas el motor de almacenamiento MyISAM en MySql:

- DISABLE KEYS: deja de actualizar los indices no unicos (nonunique).
- ENABLE KEYS: recrea los indices.

Se utilizan al restaurar un backup ya que es mucho mas rapido insertar todas las filas sin los indices activados, y luego recrearlos al final; que ir actulizando los indices a medida que se inserta cada fila.